# XE5 TStringList

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5, tstringlist

I am using Delphi XE5 Professional to develop Android App. App is running on my Galaxy S3 phone with Android 4.1.2. I probabbly don't understand, how does TStringList works. Here is what I am trying

In my FireMonkey Mobile Form I have 4 TEdits named: edt1, edt2, edt3, edt4

First I create List: TStringList

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;    
begin
  List := TStringList.Create;
  for i := 1 to 4 do List.Add(IntToStr(i));
end;
```

with an obvious structure [1 2 3 4]. Then I delete 2nd Item:

```
procedure TForm1.btnDeleteItem;
begin
  List.BeginUpdate;
  List.Delete(1);
  List.EndUpdate;
end;
```

After this procedure List has structure [1 3 4]. Problems come with the next procedure - here I try to copy data from List to my edits, so edt1 contains List[0], edt2 contains List[1],... Here is code for doing so:

```
procedure TForm1.HandleEditButtons(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
  aEdt: TEdit;
begin
  for i := 1 to 4 do 
  begin
    aEdt := FindComponent('edt'+IntToStr(i)) as TEdit;
    if (aEdt <> nil) then
      if (i <= List.Count) then aEdt.Text := List[i-1]
        else aEdt.Text := '';
  end; 
end;
```

After this procedure, List has structure [1 2 3] so it seems to me, when with procedure btnDeleteItem the last item was from List Deleted. Structures of List, which I present here, was got by using Memo1.Lines.Add(List.Text) between procedures.

Does anyone has any idea, what is happening here?

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to reproduce the problem. The code you showed cannot cause the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible way the `HandleEditButtons()` code you have shown can be altering your `List` the way you claim. Something else has to be going on in code you have not shown.

Comment: Never drink beer, when programming :). I had stupid procedure on OnChange event of each of my TEdits - when something on edit changed, List was overwriten with new data on TEdits. Thanks a lot.